# Creating matrix using array

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I made an array matrix and used for loops, the problem is that it only displays my last input. **Please refer to the sample result below.**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
 {
   int x = 0, y = 0;
   int a[x][y], i, j;

cout<<"Enter number of Columns: ";
cin>>y;

cout<<"Enter number of Rows: ";
cin>>x;

       cout<<endl;

 for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter values or row/s: ";
        cout<<endl;
                            
for(j=0; j<y; j++)
{
    cout<<endl;
    
    cout<<"Row "<< i+1 << ": ";
    cin >> a[i][j]; 
   }
   }

cout<<endl;

cout<<"Entered Matrix is: ";

cout<<endl;

for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<y; j++)
    
        cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
        
    cout<<endl;
    
     }


   }
```

**SAMPLE RESULT:**

Enter number of Columns: 3

Enter number of Rows: 2

Enter values or row/s:

Row 1: -1

Row 1: -2

Row 1: -3

Enter values or row/s:

Row 2: 4

Row 2: 5

Row 2: -6

Entered Matrix is:

4  5  -6

4  5  -6

Comment: There are so many repeats of this particular piece of code, that I question, ***what*** internet source people get this from. That source ought to stop exist. Even if we decide that using VLA is fine (ISO C++ compliance *allows* extensions),  what you do first is to declare an array of zero size (which isn't compliant to C++) and they try to change values of variables which defined that. Do people copy this from early 90s QBASIC? That was a bug, not a feature, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change declaration of array like this:

int[x][y] to int[10][10]

Comment: Thank you, can you explain to me why it should be [10]?

Comment: That is really a bad anser. It is wrong in the respect to use the magic number 10 as array size and it gives no further explanation whatsoever. Please consider to edit it or delete the answer. I normally do not answer such questions, but I will to show you some minimu standards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you want to use arrays with a variable size. So, input "x" and "y" and then use this as the array size. (`array[x][y]`)

This does not work in C++. There are no dynamic, so called VLAs (Variable Length Arrays) in C++.

There are some dialects or compiler extensions, which can handle VLA, but C++ does not allow VLAs.

This means, you cannot write somthing like:

```
int arraySize{}; 
std::cin >> arraySize;
int array[arraySize];
```

This is invalid C++ code.

C-Style arrays must have a compile time constant value. You can define it with `const` or `constexpr` or even a number literal like `42`. Magic constants liek 42 or the worst solution. Anyway, you could write

```
constepxr int arraySize = 42; 
int array[arraySize];
```

This is syntactically correct.

But, it will not help you. Because you need something "dynamic". The idiomatic correct approach in C++ is to use a `std::vector`. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) about that. And using a 2d `std::vector` the C++ solution would look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Get user input. Size of matrix. Number of rows and columns
    std::cout << "\nEnter number of Rows:      ";
    if (size_t numberOfRows{}; (std::cin >> numberOfRows) and (numberOfRows > 0)) {

        std::cout << "\nEnter number of columns:   ";
        if (size_t numberOfColumns{}; (std::cin >> numberOfColumns) and (numberOfColumns > 0)) {

            // Define 2d matrix and initialze all values to 0
            std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfColumns, 0));

            // Read all values of matrix
            std::cout << "\n\Please enter matrix values in row-column order:\n";
            for (std::vector<int>& row : matrix)
                for (int& column : row)
                    std::cin >> column;

            // Now show matrix
            std::cout << "\n\nThe entered Matrix is:\n\n";
            for (std::vector<int>& row : matrix) {
                for (int& column : row) std::cout << column << ' ';
                std::cout << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But, next, we often hear the statement that you did not learn about `std::vector` yet. And then, you need to use the approach to use old style memory allocation using `new` and `delete`. This is a non-recommend approach, but for teaching purposes, it is still often used.

So, you first allocate memory that will hold pointers to `array` (for the rows) and then allocate memory for the columns in the rows.

This would then look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Get user input. Size of matrix. Number of rows and columns
    std::cout << "\nEnter number of Rows:      ";
    if (size_t numberOfRows{}; (std::cin >> numberOfRows) and (numberOfRows > 0)) {

        std::cout << "\nEnter number of columns:   ";
        if (size_t numberOfColumns{}; (std::cin >> numberOfColumns) and (numberOfColumns > 0)) {

            // Define 2d matrix 
            int** matrix;
            matrix = new int* [numberOfRows];
            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
                matrix[row] = new int[numberOfColumns];
            

            // Read all values of matrix
            std::cout << "\n\Please enter matrix values in row-column order:\n";
            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
                for (int column=0; column < numberOfColumns; ++column)
                    std::cin >> matrix[row][column];

            // Now show matrix
            std::cout << "\n\nThe entered Matrix is:\n\n";
            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
                for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; ++column) std::cout << matrix[row][column] << ' ';
                std::cout << '\n';
            }

            // Release memory
            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; ++row)
                delete [] matrix[row];
            delete matrix;
        }
    }
}
```

As said, often teached, but strongly discouraged.

Comment: A little nitpick: VLA's as a feature of C are automatic, not dynamic arrays and are extension to C++ in a number of compilers.

Comment: Yes, correct. Thank you for the clarification